# "Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure." error when trying to plot with Matplotlib on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, python3, matplotlib

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I've recently installed Matplotlib for Python 3.9 and when I try to plot a graph it gives me the error:

```
Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
```

Do I have to install something else for it to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you have to. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56675620/3140225) to this [similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56656777/3140225) suggests that the problem is that `tkinter` is not installed. You can install it using:

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```